# finding patterns in sequence of dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with 3 column (id(int),date(date),Status(bool)) .

like this

```
id  date        Status
1   2012-10-18  1
1   2012-10-19  1
1   2012-10-20  0
1   2012-10-21  0
1   2012-10-22  0
1   2012-10-23  0
1   2012-10-24  1
1   2012-10-25  0
1   2012-10-26  0
1   2012-10-27  0
1   2012-10-28  1
2   2012-10-19  0
2   2012-10-20  0
2   2012-10-21  0
2   2012-10-22  1
2   2012-10-23  1
```

assume that date column are sequential and there is no gap between dates.

**How can I find all 3 sequential zeros (in Status column) and their next day status ?**

like this

```
id  startDate     endDate       NextDayStatus
1   2012-10-20    2012-10-22         0
1   2012-10-21    2012-10-23         1
1   2012-10-25    2012-10-27         1
2   2012-10-19    2012-10-21         1
```

table creation script and sample data

```
CREATE TABLE [Table1](
    [ID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  (  [ID] ASC,   [Date] ASC ) )

INSERT INTO [Table1]([ID], [Date], [Status])     
SELECT 1, '2012-10-18', 1    UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '2012-10-19', 1    UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '2012-10-20', 0    UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '2012-10-21', 0    UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '2012-10-22', 0    UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '2012-10-23', 0    UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '2012-10-24', 1    UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, '2012-10-25', 0    UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '2012-10-26', 0    UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '2012-10-27', 0    UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '2012-10-28', 1    UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2012-10-19', 0    UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2012-10-20', 0    UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2012-10-21', 0    UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2012-10-22', 1    UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2012-10-23', 1
```

update:

- if it matters, after this step i only need to filter out the days
  that are  first ,10th or 20th of the month
- with many thanks to Tomalak and gnb ,in my real task the number of consecutive zeros is **9** instead of 3 in this sample , so using 9 inner joins or cross apply seems inefficient

Comment: What version of SQL Server? 2012?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2

Comment: APPLY is better then 9 JOINs. But you are not on SQL Server 2012 so this is what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit, updated for ID partitioning

This also works if dates are not consecutive

```
SELECT        T1.id, T1.[Date], MAX(X.[Date]), Y.[Status]
FROM     Table1 T1       
   CROSS APPLY
   (  SELECT TOP 3 *
   FROM            Table1 T2
   WHERE           T2.id = T1.id AND T2.[Date] >= T1.Date
   ORDER BY        T2.[Date]
   ) X
   CROSS APPLY
   ( SELECT TOP 4 *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY T3.[Date]) AS rn
   FROM            Table1 T3
   WHERE           T3.id = T1.id AND T3.[Date] >= T1.Date
   ORDER BY        T3.[Date]
   ) Y
WHERE        y.rn = 4
GROUP BY     T1.id, T1.[Date], Y.[Status]
HAVING       SUM(CAST(X.[Status] AS tinyint)) = 0;
```

For completeness, this is the way more elegant SQL Server 2012 solution
This can be used with any RDBMS with proper windowing/analytic support

```
SELECT
    X.id, X.startDate, X.endDate, x.nextStatus
FROM
    ( SELECT        T1.id, T1.[Date] AS startDate,
        LEAD(T1.[Date], 2) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.id ORDER BY T1.[Date]) AS endDate,
        LEAD(T1.[Status], 3) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.id ORDER BY T1.[Date]) AS nextStatus,
        SUM(CAST(T1.[Status] AS tinyint)) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.id ORDER BY T1.[Date] ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) AS SumNext3
    FROM            Table1 T1
    ) X
WHERE        SumNext3 = 0;
```

Comment: @imanabidi: of course, the id now breaks GROUP BY,. For the new sample data, add desired output

Comment: yeas, it also breaks the ROW_NUMBER() , so i am trying to make your brilliant idea to suit my main problem, but so far no gain, please update your answer if you have time , because i know you are much much better than me at this.

Comment: @imanabidi: done, on the assumption each sequence is "per id"

Comment: excellent, I finally understand it, and it simply works for 9 days patterns with minor modification ,thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  z1.id, z1.[date] AS startDate ,z3.[date] AS endDate, zn.status AS NextDayStatus
FROM 
  Table1 z1
  INNER JOIN Table1 z2 ON z2.[date] = (
    SELECT MIN([date]) FROM Table1 WHERE [date] > z1.[date] AND id = z1.id
  )
  INNER JOIN Table1 z3 ON z3.Date = (
    SELECT MIN([date]) FROM Table1 WHERE [date] > z2.[date] AND id = z1.id
  )
  INNER JOIN Table1 zn ON zn.Date = (
    SELECT MIN([date]) FROM Table1 WHERE [date] > z3.[date] AND id = z1.id
  )
WHERE 
  z1.status = 0
  AND z2.status = 0 AND z2.id = z1.id
  AND z3.status = 0 AND z3.id = z1.id
  AND zn.id = z1.id
ORDER BY
  z1.id, z1.[date]
```

An index on Table1 `(date, status, id)` would be optimal.

Comment: dear Tomalak, this does not seem to work.i test it a few times with thew new id=2 rows added

Comment: @imanabidi You are right, I did not incorporate a condition that effectively groups on `id`. See modified answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution that would also work in many SQL products (those that support window functions), but particularly on SQL Server 2005 and later versions:

```
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    grp = DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Date)
        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Status ORDER BY Date)
  FROM Table1
),
grouped AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    SD = MIN(Date),
    ED = MAX(Date)
  FROM partitioned
  WHERE Status = 0
  GROUP BY
    ID,
    grp
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
)
SELECT
  t.ID,
  StartDate     = t.Date,
  EndDate       = DATEADD(DAY, 2, t.Date),
  NextDayStatus = CASE t.Date WHEN DATEADD(DAY, -2, g.ED) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN grouped g
ON t.ID = g.ID AND t.Date BETWEEN g.SD AND DATEADD(DAY, -2, g.ED)
;
```

The idea is to detect all the "islands" of `Status = 0`, pick those that have at least 3 rows and then join the aggregated island set back to the original table to get the rows qualifying to be the beginnings of the required subsets of 3 consecutive `Status = 0` rows.

One note, though: this solution assumes that any 3 consecutive Status 0 rows are followed by at least one other row with the same ID. In other words, the last matching set of Status 0 rows is supposed to be followed by a Status 1 row, for that's what the resulting set would indicate anyway.